# Natural manifold topology vs. product topology

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, where the first factor is endowed with the discrete topology and the second with the usual Euclidean topology and so $M$ has the resulting product topology. Show that $M$ admits a differentiable structure such that the natural manifold topology on $M$ is the product topology, hence in particular not second countable.

---

While trying to solve this I encountered some contradiction. I am quite sure my reasoning fails somewhere, but I am not too sure where. Here's my approach:

$${}$$

**( I )** $\enspace$ The product topology is the topology such that the canonical projections are all continuous. Equivalently, the preimages of open sets under the canonical projections form a subbasis. In the above case of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ this means that the open sets are of the form

$$ \{ x \} \times (a,b) \quad , \qquad x \in \mathbb{R},  \; a < b \quad . \tag{$\ast$}$$

and unions thereof. (Correct?)

**( II )** $\enspace$ The natural manifold topology is the topology such that for a maximal atlas $A_{max} = \{ \, (\phi_i, U_i ) \; | \; i \in I \, \}$ the set $\{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$ forms a basis.

**( III )** $\enspace$ I now define an atlas as $A = \{ \, (id_{\mathbb{R}^2}, V ) \; | \; V \in \tau_{\text{euclidean}} \, \}$, which obviously consists of all identity maps on open sets with respect to Euclidean topology. I now want to show that all $V \in \tau_{\text{euclidean}}$ are also elements of $\tau_{\text{product}}$.

**( IV )** $\enspace$ In order to show said property, I just have to express an open ball (because every open set in Euclidean topology is the union of such balls) in terms of these "sliced intervals" in $(\ast)$. So for an open Ball with radius $r > 0$ and center $(m_1,m_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$:

$$ B_r(m) \enspace = \enspace \bigcup_{x \in (m_1-r,m_1+r)} \{x\} \times (m_2 - \varepsilon_x, m_2 + \varepsilon_x) \quad , \qquad \varepsilon_x = r \cdot \cos \big[ \tfrac{\pi}{2r}(x-m_1) \big] $$

Which shows that the open sets $V \in \tau_{\text{euclidean}}$ are also $V \in \tau_{\text{product}}$ and by the convenient choice of coordinate charts being the identity, these charts $id_{\mathbb{R}^2} : V \longrightarrow V$ are homeomorphisms with respect to $\tau_{\text{product}}$. This, however, would mean that $\tau_{\text{euclidean}} = \tau_{\text{product}}$, **contradicting** that $M$ is not second-countable.

$${}$$

Where am I wrong? Which concept do I misunderstand?

Comment: The Euclidean topology was only applied to one factor in the product topology. $M$ is a one-dimensional manifold, not a $2$-dimensional manifold. In particular, if $V$ is a subspace of $M$ which is open in the Euclidean topology kn $M,$ then it cannot be a chart.

Comment: The charts for the topology must be on the subsets of the form $\{x\}\times \mathbb R.$

Comment: In particular, there can be no chart on $V$ such that $\pi_1(V)$ is uncountable. It might be worthwile to not think of the first $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R,$ which has a lot of intuitive connotations. Istead, think of $M$ as $S\times \mathbb R$ where $S$ is a discrete topology on a set of cardinality the continuum.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am afraid I don't really understand your answer. $M$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (only not with the euclidean topology) and therefore 2-dimensional (right?).

Comment: No, as a manifold, $M$ is one-dimensional. Consider that $\{x\}\times(a,b)$ is an open set in $M,$ but is not homeomorphic to any open subspace of Euclidean $2$-dimensional space. What would happen if, instead of $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R,$ the question was about $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R?$ Would that space be $2$-dimensional?

Comment: In general, if $X$ is a discrete topology and $N$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold, then $X\times N$ is $n$-dimensional. Even more general, if $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is any space, then the product topology on $X\times Y$ makes the space homeomorphic to the disjoint union of $|X|$ copies of the space $Y.$

Comment: Do you think $M$ with this topology is path connected? Hint: The only paths in a discrete topology are constant, and a path in a product space $X\times Y$ is equivalent to a pair of paths, one in $X$ and one in$Y.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank your for your answers! I now understand my misconception. I will need to think about this and when I am done, I will update my progress. Thanks again for your input and your help!

Comment: Another way to think of it is that a discrete topology is a $0$-dimensional manifold. (This might be literally true, depending on how you define manifold, but even if not, if you consider $0$-dimensional Euclidean space as the space with a single point, then a space has a $0$-dimensional chart if and only if every singleton is open, and thus the topology is discrete.) Then the same proof which shows that the product of an $m$- and an $n$-dimensional manifold is an $m+n$-dimensional manifold works for $0$-dimensional manifolds, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is confusing you. $M$ is not a two-dimensional manifold, it is a $1$-dimensional manifold.

If $\tau_d,\tau_e$ are the discrete and Euclidean topologies on $\mathbb R$ then $(\mathbb R,\tau_e)$ is a $1$-dimensional manifold, practically by definition.

But $(\mathbb R,\tau_d)$ is a $0$-dimensional manifold. This partly depends on whether your definition allows $0$-manifolds, but all the same rules work if we treat $\mathbb R^0$ as the space with a single point. Then a topology is a $0$-dimensional manifold if and only if it is discrete.

Then the result:

> If $M$ and $N$ are manifolds of dimension $m,n$ then $M\times N$ with the product topology is a manifold of dimension $m+n.$

still works if $m$ or $n$ or both are zero.

Your basis in the first step shows this. There can be no $2$-dimensional chart on $\{x\}\times(a,b),$ which is trivially homeomorphic to $(a,b),$ which is obviously $1$-dimensional topology.

One way to get a better intuition is that any path $\gamma:[0,1]\to X,$ where $X$ is a discrete topology, is a constant path.

In particular, the path connected components of your $M$ are thus of the form $\{x\}\times\mathbb R.$ But the Euclidean $2$ charts you propose would use open subsets which aren’t path connected. They might “look connected,” but that is because we imagine $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ with particular metric.

The reality of the discrete topology on $\mathbb R$ is hard to imagine, but it might be worth thinking instead of $M’=\mathbb N\times\mathbb R.$ It is intuitive that $M’$ is, topologically, a union of disjoint lines.

The same is true for $X\times\mathbb R$ for any discrete space $X.$ It is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of $|X|$ copies of the real line. But we can’t really picture it when $X$ is uncountable.

Comment: I thank you once again. One last question regarding the 2nd-countability of $M$. Uncountable spaces with discrete topology are not 2nd-countable. To show that $M$ is also not second-countable, is the following reasoning ok?
$${}$$
Let $B$ be a countable basis of $M$. Let $U$ be open in $(\mathbb{R},  \tau_{discr.})$. Then the preimage $\pi_1(U)$ is open in $M$ by continuity of $\pi$ and one finds:
$$\pi_1^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{V \in C \subseteq B} V \Longrightarrow U = \bigcup_{V \in C \subseteq B} \pi_1(V)$$
which implies that $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{discr.})$ is 2nd-countable - a contradiction.

Comment: Well, the lack of second countability can be seen since $U_x=\{x\}\times \mathbb R$ are all disjoint, non-empty and open, and thus must contain a basis element, $B_x.$ So the $B_x$ are an uncountable set of disjoint and hence distinct elements of the basis.